# Problemas para consultar en php y devolver a pyhton

Tags: python, python-3.7

estoy intentando una consulta de mysql via php para devolverla a python. El servidor se esta ejecutando sobre php 7.318

No consigo que devuelva lo que toca.

La consulata la ejecuto desde python llamando a una pagina de php

```
import requests
messaje={'led':'vamos a ver si entra'}
req = requests.get(url='*******/prueba.php' , params=messaje )
print(req.text )
```

En el print me gustaría recoger un jason con todas las filas de una tabla. El documento de php es así.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "*****", "****", "*******");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló la conexión con MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo "Éxito: Se realizó una conexión apropiada a MySQL! La base de datos mi_bd es genial." . PHP_EOL;


$q  = "SELECT * FROM licencias";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $q);
    $emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
echo json_encode($emparray);
$mysqli -> close();
?>
```

$emparray no contiene nada y si cambio el codigo y dentro del while meto

```
$emparray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo json_encode($row);
       # array_push($emparray, json_encode($row));
        //$emparray[] = $row;
    }
```

La última fila no la veo.

Alguien me puede ayudar para saber que está mal.Gracias.

Se que podría hacer la consulta directamente con python pero si cogen el .py  verían los datos de conexión a la database, por eso estoy montando este follón, de que python ejecute un comando y espere ser devuelto el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

intenta esta parte del codigo:

```
for ($emparray = array (); $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); $emparray[] = $row);
$mysqli -> close();
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

Comment: Buenos días no me funciona, devuelve vació  esto no se por que no le gusta `$emparray[] = $row` . Gracias Os dejo La version de PHP version  7.4.6 as FPM application  por si tuviera algo que ver .